# Wake up screen and show dialog on Lock Screen

Tags: android, wakelock, keyguardlock

I have an alarm scheduled.  Using `WakeLock.acquire()` and `KeyguardLock.disableKeyguard()`, I am able to wake the screen up and show my activity.  However, I'd prefer to just show a dialog.  The built in alarm on my HTC and Samsung devices act this way.  I expected to find a method on the KeyguardLock object, but I didn't see anything in the docs that led me in this direction.  How can I keep the KeyguardLock on, but show my dialog on it the way the built-in alarms do.  Here is my current code that runs in `onCreate()`

```
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock(KeyguardLockTag);
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    int flags = PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP;
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(flags, WakeLockTag);
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @Behzad I didn't end up doing it as described, but looking back now (this thread is over a year old), you can style your activity like a dialog to achieve the same result.  If you're not familiar how to do this, Google "android style activity as dialog".  It's easily done in the Activity element in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this to wake your device screen even at lock.

```
package android.taskscheduler;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class WakeIntentService extends IntentService
{
abstract void doReminderWork(Intent intent);
public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC = "your_package_name";
private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic = null;

public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context){
   getLock(context).acquire();
}

synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context)
{
   if(lockStatic == null)
       {
           PowerManager powManager = (PowerManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

   lockStatic = powManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
   lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
   }
   return (lockStatic);
}
public WakeIntentService(String name) 
{
   super(name);
}
@Override
        final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
       try{
            doReminderWork(intent);

        }finally
   {
       getLock(this).release();

       }
   }
}
```