# How I can add a dialog in the lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am working in a application for show last news, and i want to see in the the lock screen the latest news, and if possible you can interact with them.

I have read the others them related to customizing the lock screen but no solution has worked:

[Questions regarding Using AlarmManager with locked screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511126/questions-regarding-using-alarmmanager-with-locked-screen/18251125?noredirect=1#comment26763884_18251125)

[Keyguard Manager not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520464/keyguard-manager-not-working-properly)

[Wake up screen and show dialog on Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221456/wake-up-screen-and-show-dialog-on-lock-screen?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505398/secure-keyguard-always-shows-up-between-activities

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.2 introduced [LockScreen Widgets](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen). It looks like what your are searching for

Comment: Thanks did not know that possibility, even so there was no thought of a widget because I want to be shown automatically when you install the application, the user does not have to place it there, possible?

Comment: @user2685608 that kind of defeats the purpose of having a lock screen when the user can't control what goes there.

Comment: So, how work this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iphone5.slider for example?¿?

Comment: i think it disables standard lockscreen and does some magic to interact like it